# How to use lodash filter to find objects in a list that dont have a certain property

Tags: filter, lodash

I have an array that looks like this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Test 1",
  "age": 23
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Test 2",
  "age": 62
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Test 3"
}
```

Using lodash filter, how do I filter objects where age is not defined? as in the last item with name "Test 3"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.filter()` to remove items, with `_.has()` to detect if they have the `age` property:

```js
const arr = [{"id":"1","name":"Test 1","age":23},{"id":"2","name":"Test 2","age":62},{"id":"3","name":"Test 3"}]

const result = _.filter(arr, o => _.has(o, 'age'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or use lodash/fp to generate a function:

```js
const fn = _.filter(_.has('age'))

const arr = [{"id":"1","name":"Test 1","age":23},{"id":"2","name":"Test 2","age":62},{"id":"3","name":"Test 3"}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```